# Get a return value from dynamically calling java class

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic-method

I need to get a retrun value from dynamically calling java class by passing a variable values to that calling method. I try to use the java.lang.reflect.Method;

```
PredictionManager pm = new PredictionManager();
Class invokeclass = pm.getClass();

Class[] cArg = new Class[1];
cArg[0] = Integer.class;//Instances.class;

Method lMethod = invokeclass.getMethod("showLong", cArg);
Object aaa= lMethod.invoke(pm, cArg);
```

**in there I need to pass the value as a argument. but this method needs to give the parameter type. not the parameter value.**

What can I do?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in Method.invoke(...) you should not pass the parameter types, but the actual parameter values. Please check the java documentation for [Method.invoke(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-).